# How to make make an image rotate when hovering over different image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

In my HTML code there are 2 images. When I hover over one image I want the other image to start and keep rotating until I stop hovering. How to code my css to make this happen? Both my images are png files.

First attempt: here the id of the image I hover to make the other image rotate is "image_hov" and the id of the image that is supposed to be rotating is "image_rot". Here is the html code related to the first attempt:

HTML

```
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="bot">
            <div id="chat">
                <img id="image_hov" src="C:\Users\USER\Downloads\imgs\hov.png" alt="image_hover">
                <img id="image_rot" src="C:\Users\USER\Downloads\imgs\rot.png" alt="image_rotate">
            </div>
        </span>
    
    </body>
    </html>`
```

CSS

```
 `#chat {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 280px;
    left: 1370px;
}

#image_hov {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 113px;
    right: 29.35px;
}

#image_rot {
    width: 67px;
    height: 67px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 104px;
    left: 33px;
}

#image_hov:hover , #image_rot {
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
     }`
```

```
Second attempt:
I contained "image_rot" inside of a div and tried calling the div and rotating it, hoping that the image would rotate along with it. I gave that div an id called "div_rot".
```

HTML

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<span id="bot">
    <div id="chat">
        <img id="image_hov" src="C:\Users\USER\Downloads\imgs\hov.png" alt="image_hover">
        <div id="div_rot">
        <img id="image_rot" src="C:\Users\USER\Downloads\imgs\rot.png" alt="image_rotate">
        </div>
    </div>
</span>

</body>
</html>`
```

```
CSS
    `#chat {
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 280px;
        left: 1370px;
    }
    
    #image_hov {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        
    }
    
    #div_rot {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 113px;
        right: 29.35px;
    }
    
    #image_rot {
        width: 67px;
        height: 67px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 104px;
        left: 33px;
    }
    
    #image_hov:hover , #div_rot {
        animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
         }`
```

None of the above attempts worked. Can anyone help me find where I went wrong?
or: How should I update the code to make this work?

I will be very thankful

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```css
#image1:hover~#image2 {
  animation: rotateImg 3s linear infinite;
}

#image2:hover~#image1 {
  animation: rotateImg 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateImg {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="bot">
    <div id="chat">
      <img id="image1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image_hover">
      <img id="image2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="image_rotate">
    </div>
  </span>

</body>

</html>
```

This uses the ~, which is the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). This means that when an element with id image1 is hovered, it looks for the next element with id image2 and applies the animation there. Sadly this only works for the next element (so only when image1 is hovered). You would need to use JavaScript to make it work the other way as well. I hope this fixes the issue.

Also you will need to reapply your other styles.

Comment: thanks very much for stopping to reply....:)))

Answer (score 0):

In your code I don't see the rotation animation, to use CSS animation, you must first specify some keyframes for the animation.

Also you don't use the right selector, you should use `+` or `~`

Your HTML code is not valid, div not allowed as child of span. You can check your code validation with a HTML validator, like W3C`s validator
[validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Check the documentation about selectors: [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```css
#image_hov:hover ~ #image_rot {
      animation: rotateAnimation 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="image_hov">asdasd</h1>


   <h1 id="image_rot">asdasd</h1>
```

Comment: thanks very much... I noted the two mistakes I did...another last question is there any way to make this work without using a "keyframes" function?

Comment: It`s easier with keyframes, but you can write animation without keyframe too. Update the hover selector like this:

 transition: transform 2s linear infinite;
 transform: rotate(360deg);

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is not correct. To achieve what you want you need to point a CSS animation to the image hover selector:

```css
.image{
   border-radius: 50%;
}

.image:hover {
      animation: rotateImg 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateImg {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="image_hover">
<img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="image_rotate">
```